# Does Redshift store timestamp of last accessed?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I'd like to know how frequently certain records in a table in Redshift are being accessed. My hunch is that a large number of records in my table are queried less than once a month. If this is the case, then perhaps I can remove these records to make the table smaller.

Hence the question: **is there a way to find out the last time a record was part of a query result set?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but no, there is no way to do this with Redshift.

Comment: I see. Do you have any suggestions for how I can know the frequency with which records are accessed? Note that multiple users can query against the same table.

Comment: The best way to approach this may be to analyse the log of the actual queries being executed. depending on how complex these are it may be possible to programmatically process them to identify hot spots / unused ranges.